# Finding the roots the correct way

Tags: logic

I factorised $x$, giving $x(x-1) = 6$, ultimately giving $x = 6$ and $x = 7$.

Looked at the mark scheme and realised I had to do $x^2 - x - 6$ and factorise the quadratic to give $x = 3$ and $x = -2$. These are the correct solutions.

This looks like such a silly mistake in hindsight, but I have made this mistake twice before. So, I need to know why can you not do the first method and rather the second method.

Comment: Notice that if you plug x = 6 into that original equation you found (x(x-1) = 6), then you get 6 x 7 = 6- which is clearly wrong. You need to set the other side of the equation to 0, because otherwise, you cannot know for sure that one of the factors must be a certain value.

Comment: *why can you not do the first method and rather the second method* --- If the product of two numbers is zero, then at least one of the two numbers must be zero. This is the basis for the second method. However, if the product of two numbers is equal to some nonzero number $N,$ then any of these possibilities could occur: (1) Both numbers are equal to $N$ (e.g. when $N=1$ and the product is $1 \cdot 1).$ (2) Exactly one of the numbers is equal to $N$ (e.g. when $N=6$ and the product is $1 \cdot 6).$ (3) Neither of the numbers is equal to $N$ (e.g. when $N=6$ and the product is $2\cdot 3).$

Comment: There are an infinite number of possible numbers a and b so that ab = 6. If you know that ab = 0, and a is not b, then you know that one of a or b is 0.

Comment: @Paul you are right. But if $(x-p)(x-q)=ab$ then there is only two possible way to rewrite $ab$ as $(?-p)(?-q)$. Possible values of ? is $1/2 (-\sqrt{4 a b + p^2 - 2 p q + q^2} + p + q), 1/2 (\sqrt{4 a b + p^2 - 2 p q + q^2} + p + q)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first method is incorrect because in order to factorise a quadratic, you need to make the value equal zero so that you can find the two values of $x$, and therefore you can solve it, but in the first method you have made the value $6$ instead of $0$, so therefore you cannot solve it properly. Hope this helps.

Comment: It seems to me that you are simply saying (with a few extra words) that the first method is not correct and the second method is correct. The question is why this is true.

Answer (score 1):

"I factorised $x$
, giving $x(x−1)=6$
, ultimately giving $x=6$
and $x=7$" it is a wrong conclusion.
You can try,

$x(x-1) = 6\Leftrightarrow x(x-1)=3\times(3-1)\Leftrightarrow x(x-1)=(-2)\times((-2)-1)$[We can write $6$ as $3\times(3-1)$ or $(-2)\times((-2)-1)$] By comparing both side we get $x=3,-2$

But, It is not a correct way to approach the equation. You should factorise the Left Hand Side and make Right Hand Side Zero. Or, solve the quadratic equation with any othe method you prefer.